# How to load various images using a loop

Tags: python

Im making a calculator using Pygame, and to simplify the code, im trying to load all those variables in an easier way.

```
one = pygame.image.load("img/1.png")
two = pygame.image.load("img/2.png")
three = pygame.image.load("img/3.png")
four = pygame.image.load("img/4.png")
five = pygame.image.load("img/5.png")
six = pygame.image.load("img/6.png")
seven = pygame.image.load("img/7.png")
eight = pygame.image.load("img/8.png")
nine = pygame.image.load("img/9.png")
zero = pygame.image.load("img/0.png")
```

I thought of this:

```
numeros = ["uno","dos","tres","cuatro","cinco","seis","siete","ocho","nueve","cero"]
for x in numeros:
    def load(x):
        x = pygame.image.load("img/" + x +".png")
        time.sleep(0.1)
        print(x)
```

but when i try to screen.blit(uno),for example, it ways "uno is not defined",even though i defined it in the function.

For anyone curious, this is the rest of my code. Any advice would be greatly appreciated on how to make it less messy, im a beginner.

```
import pygame
from sys import exit
import random
import time
#starts pygame (images and sounds)
pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.init()
#create screen variable
width = 560
height = 700
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width,height))

#ponerle titulo
pygame.display.set_caption("Calculator")

#reloj/framerate
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
fondo = pygame.Surface((560,700))
fondo.fill("gray")
one = pygame.image.load("img/1.png")
two = pygame.image.load("img/2.png")
three = pygame.image.load("img/3.png")
four = pygame.image.load("img/4.png")
five = pygame.image.load("img/5.png")
six = pygame.image.load("img/6.png")
seven = pygame.image.load("img/7.png")
eight = pygame.image.load("img/8.png")
nine = pygame.image.load("img/9.png")
zero = pygame.image.load("img/0.png")
suma = pygame.image.load("img/suma.png")
resta = pygame.image.load("img/resta.png")
multiplicacion = pygame.image.load("img/multiplicacion.png")
division = pygame.image.load("img/division.png")
igual = pygame.image.load("img/igual2.png")
raton = pygame.Surface((1,1))

number1active = "Active"
number2active = "Inactive"
signo = "nada"
number1 = ""
number2 = ""
number1score = pygame.font.Font("fonts/Pixeltype.ttf",100)
number2score = pygame.font.Font("fonts/Pixeltype.ttf",100)
resultadoscore = pygame.font.Font("fonts/Pixeltype.ttf",100)
resultado = 0
resultadofinal = False
while True: 
    for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.QUIT()
                exit()
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                if resultadofinal == 1:
                    resultadofinal = 0
                    number1 = ""
                    number2 = ""
                    resultado = 0
                    number1active ="Active"
                if 0 < xraton < 130 and 100 < yraton < 240:
                    if number1active == "Active":
                        number1 = number1 + "1"
                    elif number2active == "Active":
                        number2 = number2 + "1"
                if 140 < xraton < 270 and 100 < yraton < 240:
                    if number1active == "Active":
                        number1 = number1 + "2"
                    elif number2active == "Active":
                        number2 = number2 + "2" 
                if 280 < xraton < 410 and 100 < yraton < 240:
                    if number1active == "Active":
                        number1 = number1 + "3"
                    elif number2active == "Active":
                        number2 = number2 + "3"
                if 0 < xraton < 130 and 250 < yraton < 390:
                    if number1active == "Active":
                        number1 = number1 + "4"
                    elif number2active == "Active":
                        number2 = number2 + "4"
                if 140 < xraton < 270 and 250 < yraton < 390:
                    if number1active == "Active":
                        number1 = number1 + "5"
                    elif number2active == "Active":
                        number2 = number2 + "5"
                if 280 < xraton < 410 and 250 < yraton < 390:
                    if number1active == "Active":
                        number1 = number1 + "6"
                    elif number2active == "Active":
                        number2 = number2 + "6"
                if 0 < xraton < 130 and 400 < yraton < 540:
                    if number1active == "Active":
                        number1 = number1 + "7"
                    elif number2active == "Active":
                        number2 = number2 + "7"
                if 140 < xraton < 270 and 400 < yraton < 540:
                    if number1active == "Active":
                        number1 = number1 + "8"
                    elif number2active == "Active":
                        number2 = number2 + "8"
                if 280 < xraton < 410 and 400 < yraton < 540:
                    if number1active == "Active":
                        number1 = number1 + "9"
                    elif number2active == "Active":
                        number2 = number2 + "9"
                if 0 < xraton < 130 and 550 < yraton < 690:
                    if number1active == "Active":
                        number1 = number1 + "0"
                    elif number2active == "Active":
                        number2 = number2 + "0"
                if 420 < xraton < 550 and 100 < yraton < 240:
                    signo = "+"
                    number1active = "Inactive"
                    number2active = "Active"
                if 420 < xraton < 550 and 250 < yraton < 390:
                    signo = "-"
                    number1active = "Inactive"
                    number2active = "Active"
                if 420 < xraton < 550 and 400 < yraton < 540:
                    signo = "*"
                    number1active = "Inactive"
                    number2active = "Active"
                if 420 < xraton < 550 and 550 < yraton < 690:
                    signo = "/"
                    number1active = "Inactive"
                    number2active = "Active"
                if 140 < xraton < 410 and 550 < yraton < 690:
                    resultadofinal = 1
                    number2active = "Inactive"
                    if signo == "+":
                        resultado = int(number1) + int(number2)
                    elif signo == "-":
                        resultado = int(number1) - int(number2)
                    elif signo == "*":
                        resultado = int(number1) * int(number2)
                    elif signo == "/":
                        resultado = int(number1) / int(number2)

            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_a:
                    if number1active == "Active":
                        number1 = number1[:-1]
                    elif number2active == "Active":
                        number2 = number2[:-1]
    
    (xraton,yraton) = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    screen.blit(fondo,(0,0))
    screen.blit(one,(0,100))
    screen.blit(two,(140,100))
    screen.blit(three,(280,100))
    screen.blit(four,(0,250))
    screen.blit(five,(140,250))
    screen.blit(six,(280,250))
    screen.blit(seven,(0,400))
    screen.blit(eight,(140,400))
    screen.blit(nine,(280,400))
    screen.blit(zero,(0,550))
    screen.blit(suma,(420,100))
    screen.blit(resta,(420,250))
    screen.blit(multiplicacion,(420,400))
    screen.blit(division,(420,550))
    screen.blit(igual,(140,550))
    number1surface = number1score.render(number1, False, (0, 0, 0))
    number2surface = number2score.render(number2, False, (0, 0, 0))
    resultadosurface = resultadoscore.render(str(resultado), False, (0, 0, 0))
    if number1active == "Active":
        screen.blit(number1surface,(10,30))  
    elif number2active == "Active":
        screen.blit(number2surface,(10,30))  
    if resultadofinal == 1:
        screen.blit(resultadosurface,(10,30))
        
    screen.blit(raton,(xraton,yraton))
    
    pygame.display.update()
```

I would very much appreciate some guidance in this problem :)

Comment: Several good answers have already been given.  I just want address a serious conceptual problem with your loop.  You loop over different values of "x", but then you keep redefining a function called load with an argument "x".  This argument "x" does not take on the values of your loop variable "x".  The arguments to a function definition are local to that definition.  You want to define your load function once before the loop and then call the function with different arguments in your loop.

Comment: In addition, assigning to that function argument "x" within the function, as you have, doesn't pass that value back out of the function.  so, assigning to "x" within the load function definition will just lead to confusion, so you should probably use a different local variable name within the load function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to store the images in a list, instead of using a separate variable for each image:

```py
numbers = []
for i in range(10):
    image = pygame.image.load("img/" + str(i) + ".png") 
    numbers.append(image)
```

or even shorter

```py
numbers = [pygame.image.load(f'img/{i}.png') for i in range(10)]
```

You can access the number images via subscription: `numbers[0]`, `numbers[1]`, ...

Answer (score 1):

String formatting and a list comprehension would do nicely here:

```py
images = [pygame.image.load(f'img/{i}.png') for i in range(10)]
```

To completely flesh this out, you could extend the list to contain the rest of the files:

```py
images = [f'img/{i}.png' for i in range(10)]

images.extend[
    f'img/{file}.png' for file in 
    ('suma', 'resta', 'multiplicacion', 'division', 'igual2')
]

images = [pygame.image.load(image) for image in images]
```